# I want to know how js or css can know when something like text in a html span is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a graph that I want to change in color when the number changes. I don't know how to do this sadly. Maybe someone can help me in the right direction of looking at least. The numbers with styling I want: 20<= green, >20 or ==30 yellow, >30 red.

[image]

Comment: There are a vast range of ways this could be done, what have you tried so far? (Please include the relevant code)

Comment: Look up MutationObserver

Comment: Might be better to have the code that updates the text to say it changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a mix of JS and CSS variables. This is one of the many ways to approach this.

```js
const colorGreen = "#64ed7b";
const colorYellow = "#ffed13";
const colorRed = "#eb4444";
const projectCount = Number(document.querySelector(".project-count").textContent);

function setColor(hex) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--projects', hex);
}


if (projectCount > 30) {
  setColor(colorRed);
} else if (projectCount > 20) {
  setColor(colorYellow);
} else {
  setColor(colorGreen);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --projects: #eb4444;
}

.projects-pending {
  border: 10px solid var(--projects);
  color: var(--projects);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-pending">
  <span class="project-count">21</span>
  <span>projects pending<span>
</div>
```

Comment: can I set the else you made in js to a else if that can also be measure its color based on what number there is? And if so, can I do it like this: else if (projectCount > 20, 30<) {
  setColor(colorYellow);

Comment: @kw1c-MuurmansLorentz I didn't understand sorry. Can you rephrase this?

Comment: nvm I doesn't matter anymore. Thank you for your time though. I dind't know how to do this and know I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MutationObserver` to get information when something changes in span. or even better from where it's changing the project pending number, you should be able to trigger a function to change the colors.

Comment: There is no change event on a span

Comment: @epascarello changed to mutationobserver